# problem IntlDateFormatter shamsi to miladi

Tags: php

I want to convert solar date to Gregorian

I wrote this piece of code using IntlDateFormatter

but not work

```
function shamsi_to_miladi($date)
{
    $now = new DateTime($date);
    $IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        'en_US@calendar=gregorian',
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
        NULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
        "Y/MM/dd"
    );
    return $IntlDateFormatter->format($now);
}
echo shamsi_to_miladi("1402/08/17");
```

try true work but not work

output 1402/07/09

but true 2023/10/11

Comment: What is not working ? Did you get an error ? Is the result different than intended ? You need to explain properly what you are trying to accomplish and what is currently happening.

Comment: output 1402/07/09

but true 2023/10/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of issues happening. First, you don't need to use a `DateTime` object as that is going to assume Gregorian reguardless. Since the input is a solar calendar date, you want to pass that into the parse function using the persian solar calendar. This will pass back a unix epoch integer which is calendar agnostic. Then convert the formatter's calendar to Gregorian so the output is in the correct format.

You were also using `Y` for the date which is "week of year" which is a different calendar calculation for year. It's best to stick with the `yyyy` standard year format to parse as the former knocks off a lot of years from the date.

As I side note, I am not all that familiar with the solar calendar but the output date you provided (2023/10/11) appears to be incorrect. I passed the solar date 1402/07/09 into multiple online converters and the answer was always 2023/11/08, which is what the function below produces:

```php
function shamsi_to_miladi($date)
{
    $IntlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        'en_US@calendar=persian',
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
        NULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
        "yyyy/MM/dd"
    );
    $shamsiTimestamp = $IntlDateFormatter->parse($date);
    // Convert from Persian calendar to Gregorian:
    $IntlDateFormatter->setCalendar(IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
    return $IntlDateFormatter->format($shamsiTimestamp);
}
echo shamsi_to_miladi("1402/08/17"); // 2023/11/08
```